# Getting Error: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' despite importing FormsModule

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have imported FormsModule in my app.module.ts  but I am still getting this error.

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

I have gone through similar posts but still I am unable to find a solution for this.

app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {NgModule  } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'


})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.component.html

```
<input type=radio name="gender" value="Mr" [(ngModel)]="gender">Male
<input type=radio name="gender" value="Mrs" [(ngModel)]="gender">Female
{{"Hello " + gender}}
```

Comment: why do you have a ngModule in appcomponent?

Comment: you should really learn how an angular apps work. The best way to start is to understand this example: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this :

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    gender: string;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type=radio name="gender" value="Mr" [(ngModel)]="gender">Male
<input type=radio name="gender" value="Mrs" [(ngModel)]="gender">Female
{{"Hello " + gender}}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot :)